# Dynamically Load Classes in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, dynamic

Is there a way to #import a class from a string in Objective-C at run time? Any methods that would produce a similar result would also be welcome.

Edit:

I want access to a class whose name I determine at runtime. So something like this:

```
NSString *className = getClassName();
Class myClass = loadClass(className);
myClass *myVar = [[myClass alloc] init];
```

Is there any way to do this without putting a static #import directive for myClass at the top of the file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `#import` directive does not "import" a class — it inserts the text from the named file into the current file. This obviously isn't useful at runtime after the source has been compiled.

What you want is to create a bundle with the classes and [dynamically load the bundle](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingCode/LoadingCode.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000052-SW1). In order to be able to talk to the classes from the core program, you'll probably want to have some common protocol that bundled classes implement.

Comment: @Jason Coco: Can't you? NSBundle is documented as working on iOS. As long as you aren't downloading external code, I'd think you would be fine.

Comment: It looks like "loadable bundles" is what I want, and according to the Apple documentation "The creation and use of loadable bundles is not supported in iOS.". I guess Apple doesn't want people making cool dynamic frameworks on iOS like I want to do, or doesn't support it yet anyway.

Comment: No, they don't work. You can load them but you can't execute code from them. It simply fails, unless they've updated that recently since they started allowing interpreted code. Even just plain old nibs won't load from a loaded bundle (although all the other resources become available, like images or sound files).

Comment: Just a note as I stumble upon this old answer to tell future visitors that even if it wasn't possible before, now since WWDC'14 and iOS SDK 8.0, dynamically load frameworks is now possible (but only when deploying for iOS8+) — as long as the dynamic framework is embedded in the iOS app bundle.

Answer (score 25):

You can use `NSClassFromString` method. So:

```
// Creates an instance of an NSObject and stores it in anObject
id anObject = [[NSClassFromString(@"NSObject") alloc] init];
```

Some more sample code in response to your edit:

```
NSString* myClassString = getClassName();
// if the class doesn't exist, myClass will be Nil and myVar will be nil
Class* myClass = NSClassFromString(myClassString);
id myVar = [[myClass alloc] init];
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this looks like it creates an instance of nil, when I would like to create an instance of myClass. Maybe this is just not possible in Objective-C? In Python I can dynamically load modules at run-time depending on application logic. I was hoping that there was a way to do this in Objective C.

Comment: @Jacob Lyles: `NSClassFromString()` returns nil if no such class was found. It sounds like your class is not loaded into the app. In that case, you might want to see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Chuck for pointing me on the right path, but the correct answer for this query seems to be that it is impossible on iOS 4.1, though it is possible with the current Mac OSX SDK using loadable bundles.

Comment: where did you mention that you were asking about IOS 4.1