# How to implement plugin feature in Objective-C (iOS5)

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

I'm developing a library for iOS, named PhotoSubmitter, to facilitate the development of photo upload application.

[PhotoSubmitter](https://github.com/kent013/tottepost/tree/master/tottepost/PhotoSubmitter)

This library can upload photo to Social Network Services and Cloud Services, there are lots of Services to support remaining.
And I want to the library to be plaggable.

I wish to know **how to implement plaggable feature in Objective-C**.

Plaggable means, when third-party service implementation for PhotoSubmitter is placed in the appropriate directory, like under `plugins`, the library automatically detect it.

If FacebookPhotoSubmitter.h/m placed in the `plugins` directory, code will be like,

`[[PhotoSubmitterFactory sharedInstance] enableService:@"Facebook"];`

And this code to be work properly with out including header "FacebookPhotoSubmitter.h" in both Client code and PhotoSubmitter library code.

If you know any of the similar implementation, please point the repository.
Any helps appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this post](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/09/17/cocoa-tutorial-adding-plugins-to-a-cocoa-application/) will be incredible helpful. (Mac OS X)

For iOS [you can't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4199500/366492) dynamically load code on a AppStore app.

Comment: While this may technically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) for you to include the essential parts of the linked article in your answer, and provide the link for reference. Failing to do that leaves the answer at risk from link rot.

Comment: @JoshCaswell you're right, despite I'm busy right now I'll be sure to keep that in mind the next time I post an answer, thanks.

Comment: @fbernardo thank you for the pointer any way, it looks helpful!

Comment: @fbernardo I read the post, and I found that I have not indicate that I'm looking for the solution in iOS... And I found in apple's document https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW30, It says "The creation and use of loadable bundles is not supported in iOS.", thank you answering question. I'll update the text.

Comment: Oh, right. Then I'll have to tell you one of the App Store rules is "no remote executable code" or something like that. Meaning, you can't "add code" to a already shipped app.

Comment: @fbernardo Finally I found this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188100/dynamically-load-classes-in-objective-c. It says, "It is impossible"... anyway I could not found it out without your post. Thanks.